# Custom Label ID for Tensorflow Object Detection

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, object-detection

I am facing to train object detection model with custom Label ID like below:

item {
  id: 1111
  name: 'c'

}item {
  id: 2545
  name: 'ch'

}item {
  id: 3758
  name: 't'

}item {
  id: 4965
  name: 'th'
}

I have already read this: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/using_your_own_dataset.md

It says "Label maps should always start from id 1." But I want to train my own dataset with random Label ID.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you’re correct that label maps start from 1. I’m not sure why you need custom ids. Why not use a dictionary to map your custom id to label map’s ids? Hope it helps?